# Death of a character in the Baratie arc

Tags: one-piece

I was watching One Piece when I remembered that there was a guy Sanji saved back in the Baratie arc. Then I looked up his name, and it was Gin.

I remember that when Krieg launched the poison attack, Gin gave his mask to Luffy, essentially sacrificing himself in the process.

They said he took a lethal amount of poison, yet we don't know if he died after the events. We only know that he and his crew (including Pandaman) sailed away on a ship that wasn't the ideal size, and Gin said to Luffy that he's going to meet him again.

Did he die? I'm quite far in the story, and he hasn't returned thus far. Challenging Luffy also wouldn't be a very sane idea if he knew he was going to be dead in couple of hours, and there's virtually no chance they meet again in that time.

Comment: @senshin Considering this happens around the 60th episode and that Gin isn't a big character, this is a vers mild spoiler, but yeah, it might be one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gin hasn't been mentioned or referenced in the story since he left, so his fate his unknown at the moment, and only speculation can be used.

On the one hand, he did breathe in a supposedly lethal amount of poisonous gases, and may not have much longer left to live, as he noted himself. But on the other hand, several characters in the series have been shown to survive supposedly lethal injuries, albeit sometimes thanks to outside help. Pell survived the explosion from Crocodile's bomb in the Alabasta arc, and Luffy survived Magellan's poisons thanks to Ivankov's treatments and his own willpower.

Until Gin reappears in person, is mentioned by another character, or Oda clarifies the situation in an SBS, Gin's fate will remain ambiguous.

Comment: I see this as a commonality between both Toriyama and Oda. Once a side character is used for awhile they slowly just fade away without having anything definitive happen to them.

Comment: Schrodinger Gin ~